# Import cost data from google spreadsheet to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

I am tryig to figure out if i am able to get data from google spreadsheet and import to google analytics. I thought of using API but i am not sure it will work or that's the only way. Anybody know excatly or something on how to sync them together?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Google Sheet's app script to upload cost data to Google Analytics.

```
function uploadData() {
  var accountId = "xxxxxxxx";
  var webPropertyId = "UA-xxxxxxxx-x";
  var customDataSourceId = "xxxxxxxx";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var maxRows = ss.getLastRow();
  var maxColumns = ss.getLastColumn();
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < maxRows;i++) {
    data.push(ss.getRange([i], 1,1, maxColumns).getValues());
  }
  var newData = data.join("\n");
  var blobData = Utilities.newBlob(newData, "application/octet-stream", "GA import data");
  try {
    var upload = Analytics.Management.Uploads.uploadData(accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId, blobData);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Uploading: OK");
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Cannot upload: Failed");
  }
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/chipoglesby/81d38c5d40d67689463d)

Comment: so once i include in the function it will be automatically upload as cost data in google analytic? @RyanPraskievicz

Comment: you'll have to include this as a Google App Script, add your specific accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSoruceId and then run the script.

Comment: i seems to have upload undefine. may i know what are the possible element that would resulted to this? thank you @RyanPraskievicz

Comment: Hi @lel here are a few thoughts: did you create the data set in the Google Analytics admin within Property > Data Import? did you include the data set ID found here in your API Apps script in your Google Sheet?

Comment: Sorry what do you meant by " include the data set ID found here in your API Apps script in your Google Sheet" @RyanPraskievicz

Comment: In the App Script  you need to make sure to fill out the xxxx with your specific account, web property, and customDataSourceID                    var accountId = "xxxxxxxx";
  var webPropertyId = "UA-xxxxxxxx-x";
  var customDataSourceId = "xxxxxxxx";

Comment: oh yes, I did fill in with my specific account, web property, and customDataSourceID found in google analytics. @RyanPraskievicz

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Sheets API to extract the data out of your sheet.  Then the management API will allow you to upload that data.

> The Uploads collection is a set of Upload resources, each of which
>   describes an upload for one of the user's custom data sources.  This
>   resource should be used when uploading Dimension Widening data.

Try [uploads](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads)